# How do I fix Bootstrap from breaking grid?

Tags: javascript, django, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

What I have:

I am using Django to populate my Makes on a view.

Here is my template:

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group" id="makesTable">
    {%  if makes %}
    {% for make in makes %}
    <button  type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" id="{{ make.id }}">
        <br />
        <img class="center-block" src="[REDACTED]"  />
        <br />
        <p>{{ make.name }}</p>
    </button>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML5 output:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="btn-group" id="makesTable">
    <button  type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" id="1">
        <br />
        <img class="center-block" src="/static/IQC/assets/img/gallery/brands/128/Acura.png"  />
        <br />
        <p>Acura</p>
    </button>

    <button  type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" id="2">
        <br />
        <img class="center-block" src="/static/IQC/assets/img/gallery/brands/128/Alfa%20Romero.png"  />
        <br />
        <p>Alfa Romero</p>
    </button>

    <button  type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-default" id="3">
        <br />
        <img class="center-block" src="/static/IQC/assets/img/gallery/brands/128/Audi.png"  />
        <br />
        <p>Audi</p>
    </button>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
```

**I am currently having an issue with responsive design. I would like for the buttons to be arranged in a 5x7 grid, however, sometimes, I get the following issue:**

[This is how I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S2Br.png)

[This is how it breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzeTU.png)

Comment: that is due to using float and differing heights... can use css flexbox instead

Comment: You can remove the `{% if makes %}`. If `makes` is empty, the for loop will automatically exit.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm a noobie to bootstrap, can you elaborate

Comment: or add new rows

Comment: create a [mcve] using html only

Comment: @charlietfl okay, I updated my question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `box-sizing: border-box;`, that should solve your issue.

Comment: where would I add this to in my template?

Comment: You should have a custom style sheet, If you are then you should put use it under the button style.

Comment: I am using bootstrap as my style sheet and I don't think it's the best idea to modify it (as I'm also using CDNs to optimize my speed.) I tried to add style="box-sizing: border-box;" to my buttons in my template as a test, and this didn't work.

Comment: You can still have a custom style sheet and still use the CDNs. This will help with things you don't like in bootstrap. 

You can refer to this : https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Comment: fairly unfamiliar with CSS so please excuse my ignorance. Okay, so I have 'bootstrap.css' and 'miquel.css' I would like to inherit ALL of bootstrap's styling for my buttons, however I would like miquel.css to have the extra parameter box-sizing that fixes my css. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah, having the bootstrap.css it will still take all of the styling, the custom sheet will just be used when you want to override a style. This should help with setting it up:https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/

Also if you make a jfiddle to demo, I can take a look at it.

Comment: I still don't understand why style="..." didn't work, and what's the point of adding it to a custom CSS if it didn't work from the test. Do you think that flexbox is a answer I'm looking for?

Comment: It could, but you will run into an issue with it working in IE. Can you put what you have in jsfiddle or codepen so I could see what youre doing?